# Primes in group theory using lagrange theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group with order pq, where p and q are primes. Show that every proper subgroup of G is cyclic.
here is what i have so far. 
Proof: Let G be a finite group, and let H < G. Let the |H| = n. So by Lagrange, |H| / |G|. Which means n|pq. so the only possible way for n to divides pq if n = 1, p, q, or pq. But how does this help me show that G is cyclic. It feels like i am not taking the right approach. Any ideas, or suggestions.

Comment: You are most definitely taking the right approach. You're supposed to show that $H$ is cyclic, not $G$. What do you know about groups of prime order? Why cannot $n$ be $pq$?

Comment: What are the possible orders for the _proper_ subgroups of $G$? What do you know about those groups?

Comment: @Arthur then how do how show that H is cyclic because all i know is the order of G

Comment: i still can not follow, i know that for a fact that if a group has prime order then the group is cyclic. What i really do not understand is how do you show that the subgroup will be a cyclic

Comment: A subgroup is a group. The prefix sub- only says that we are considering this group as a subset of another group. Therefore, a subgroup whose order is prime is also cyclic.

Comment: i got it thanks i appreciate that. Then i did solve the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a group has prime order, and $x\neq 1$ is an element, what can be the subgoup generated by $x$?